# Local Flask app get full file path from form upload

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app running locally (and it will always run locally, although potentially on different machines). This app is essentially a GUI for a local python library, which requires a file path as an argument (to then run a script on this file). I am trying to use a form with an upload field to let the user browse and select the file path in a familiar manner, however once submit is clicked, I do not want any files 'uploaded' or copied, as they are huge files. Rather, I just want to get the full path of the file the user selected in the file browser. So far I have the code below, however it only prints the file name.

flask_app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def hello():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       email = request.form.get('myfile')
       print(request.files)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

templates/index.html

```
<form method="post">
<label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

when I run this app and select, for example 'myfile.txt', it prints the following to console:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('myfile', 'myfile.txt')])
```

ideally this should read something like:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('myfile', '../../random/folder/myfile.txt')])
```

or even better an absolute path:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('myfile', 'C:/Users/me/Documents/myfile.txt')])
```

Comment: No modern browser is going to reveal the full pathname of an uploaded file, as that would be a *huge* privacy violation.

Comment: Yes, but is there a workaround to this since the app is running on localhost and I already have access to the file system? Or would I need to create a custom file browser somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print(request.files['file'])
```

Edited after OP answer:

due to security and privacy reasons, you cannot directly access the full file path of the uploaded file. Modern browsers deliberately restrict access to this information to prevent potential security risks

Comment: Hm. That gives me a file object I can then read from, but since my scripts perform read/write operations directly on a few files, I don't want to send file objects

Comment: Edited with more details about the security issues related to showing the entire path